# Alternative approaches to obtain the expected value of the geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

Given that $X$ has geometric distribution with $p_{X}(x) = p(1-p)^{x-1}$, determine $\textbf{E}(X)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp(1-p)^{x-1} = p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x(1-p)^{x-1}
\end{align*}

If we denote by

\begin{align*}
F(w) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} w^{k} = \frac{w}{1 - w}\quad\text{for}\quad |w| < 1
\end{align*}

We conclude that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X) = p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x(1-p)^{x-1} = pF^{\prime}(1-p)
\end{align*}

Since $\displaystyle F^{\prime}(w) = \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2}}$, it is now possible to obtain the desired result
\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}(X) = \frac{p}{(1-(1-p))^{2}} = \frac{1}{p}
\end{align*}

In the case that my answer is correct, could someone provide me any other approach to this problem? I'd prefer solutions which do not involve sophisticated methods. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric distribution gives the number of trials until the first success (including the successful one, in your mass function above) in a sequence of trials with probability of success $p$.

The first trial is either a success (probability $p$) or a failure (probability $1-p$); if it is a success, you are done and $X=1$.  If it is a failure, you are left with another geometric process which you must add one extra failure to.

In other words,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]=p\cdot1+(1-p)\cdot(1+\mathbb{E}[X])=1+(1-p)\mathbb{E}[X].
$$
Subtracting $(1-p)\mathbb{E}[X]$ from both sides yields
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]-(1-p)\mathbb{E}[X]=1,
$$
which simplifies to
$$
p\mathbb{E}[X]=1\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p}.
$$

Comment: Nice argument! Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is correct. You can also use a version of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem (i.e. changing order of summation):
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty j(1-p)^{j-1}&=&\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} 1\right)(1-p)^{j-1}\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty(1-p)^{j-1} \right)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^k}{p}\\
&=&\frac{1}{p^2}.
\end{eqnarray}$$ This gives
$$
\Bbb E[X]=p\sum_{j=0}^\infty j(1-p)^{j-1}=\frac{1}{p}.
$$
Note: Note that $$\binom{-2}{j}=\frac{(-2)(-3)\cdots(-1-j)}{j!}=(-1)^j(j+1).$$ Generalized binomial theorem also gives
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{-2}{j}(-x)^j=(1-x)^{-2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a slightly different way of doing this
$$ E(X) = p \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x(1-p)^{x-1} $$ 
$$ (1-p)E(X) =p\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x(1-p)^{x} $$
$$ E(X) - (1-p)E(X) = p\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^{x} $$
You can see this writing down the first few terms in each sum :
$$ E(X) = p( 1 + 2(1-p) + 3(1-p)^2 ...)$$
$$ (1-p)E(X) = p( (1-p)+ 2(1-p)^2 + 3(1-p)^3 ...) $$
$$ E(X) - (1-p)E(X) =p (1+ (1-p) + (1-p)^2 + (1-p)^3 ...) $$
$$ E(X) - (1-p)E(X) = p \frac{1}{1-(1-p)} $$
$$ E(X) =\frac{1}{p}$$